# input diccionario

Tags: python, json

Alguien sabe como agregar un diccionario completo en un input, literalmente como:

```py
dic = input("{"y":99,"k":67,"o":99}")
```

Algo así, que luego se pueda llamar de la siguiente forma:

```py
print(dic["y"])
-->return "99"
```

Si lo agrego tal cual lo pongo acá, no funciona, porque me toma el input como una lista, entonces claro, si más adelante llamo un key, para obtener su código, pues no funciona.

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día,

Para lograrlo puedes utilizar el módulo `json`

```
import json

dic = input('Ingresa un diccionario: ')

res = json.loads(dic)
```

Y ya podemos utilizar el diccionario de forma normal, por ejemplo, si agregaramos la línea

```
print(res['a'])
```

E ingresaramos el siguiente `string`: `{"a": [1,2,3,4], "b": [5,6,7,8]}`

Esto nos devolvería

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Es decir, con el módulo `json` puedes ingresar cualquier `string` con sintaxis de diccionario y puedes utilizar sus llaves y valores de la misma forma que utilizas un diccionario.

**Nota:** Al ingresar el `string` es necesario utilizar comillas dobles `"` para los nombres de las llaves.

Comment: De verdad has entendido en la pregunta que el quiere convertir un diccionario metido por el usuario?? nose... yo no veo que pregunte eso

Comment: Esto esta mas comprimido venga, funciona bien, tnk

Comment: Buen día @Bastian-SC, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero de todo, lo que está dentro del input está mal, tendrías que cambiar las comillas dobles (`"`) de dentro por comillas simples (`'`), o al revés.

Quedando así:

```py
input("{'y':99,'k':67,'o':99}")
```

Para continuar, lo que metes dentro del `input()` es un `str` que Python escribe por pantalla para decirle al usuario que meta un valor a mano. Es decir, si yo pongo `input('Hola, ¿cómo te llamas?')` Python muestra `Hola, ¿cómo te llamas?` en pantalla y se queda esperando una respuesta del usuario. Por lo tanto si tú pones `input("{'y':99,'k':67,'o':99}")`, Python mostrara en pantalla `{'y':99,'k':67,'o':99}` y se quedara esperando una respuesta, pero si el usuario introduce `y`, Python no meterá dentro de la variable un 99, sino `y` porque lo que se mete dentro del input no se usa como opciones, o algo, simplemente sirve para mostrar el texto y advertir al usuario que tiene que introducir un valor. Todo lo que mete el usuario es un `str`, ya que lo que devuelve `input()` es `str`.

Por lo tanto, si quieres que el usuario introduzca una letra y tu código tenga en cuenta que este texto equivale a un número podrías hacerlo de mil formas, te muestro una:

```py
# Inicializamos el diccionario
valores = {'y':99,'k':67,'o':99}

# Recogemos el valor que el usuario quiere
# El \n sirve para que el usuario escriba en una linea nueva, quedando visualmente mejor
letra = input("Introduce una de las letras: 'y' = 99, 'k' = 67, 'o' = 99 \n")

# Comprobamos que la letra introducida por el usuario es una letra valida, sino advertimos de que no lo es
if letra in valores.keys():
    print(valores[letra]) # Escribe 99, 67 o 99 en si el usuario mete y, k o o
else:
    print("La letra introducida no es una de las opciones")
```

Como esta hay mil formas de hacer, todo sería pensar un poco y amoldar tu código poco a poco.

Comment: Buen día, lo que está pidiendo el OP es poder convertir de `string` a diccionario, no únicamente asignar los valores a un diccionario existente

Comment: @HeytalePazguato, si, eso pregunta al principio, pero justo despues dice llamar al diccionario, no se puede hacer eso. Por lo que le he explicado el funcionamiento de `input()` y de paso enseñado un ejemplo. De todas formas yo no estoy asignando ningun valor a ningun diccionario. Un saludo.

Comment: Bien una buena respuesta si tnk

Comment: @Bastian-SC es lo que querias?